# не работает виджет yii2 imperavi

Tags: php, yii2, yii, виджет

вот документация - `https://github.com/vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget`

Нужно настроить загрузку файлов.

view:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'text')->textArea(['id' => 'my-textarea-id']) ?>



<?php  \vova07\imperavi\Widget::widget([
  'selector' => '#my-textarea-id',
  'settings' => [
       'lang' => 'ru',
        'minHeight' => 200,
        'imageUpload' => Url::to(['/file-storage/default']),
           'plugins' => [
               'imagemanager',
            ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

так же создал контроллер : `FileSorageController.php`

и поместил в него:

```
<?php

namespace controllers;

use Yii;


/**
 * FileStorageController implements the CRUD actions for FileStorageItem model.
 */
class FileStorageController extends Controller
{


    public function actions()
{
    return [
        'image-upload' => [
            'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\UploadFileAction',
            'url' => 'http://umonreal.ru/file-storage/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
            'path' => '/file-storage', // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
        ],
    ];
}

}
```

Ошибка:

> An error occurred during the upload process!

логи:

```
<pre>PHP Fatal Error &#039;yii\base\ErrorException&#039; with message &#039;Class &#039;controllers\Controller&#039; not found&#039; 

in /home/d/davgabih/team.umonreal.ru/public_html/controllers/StorageController.php:12

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler-&gt;handleFatalError()
#1 {main}</pre>
```

Comment: что в логах? такой ошибки маловато как-то, не слишком информативно

Comment: Попробуйте в контроллере добавить параметр `options` и в нем передать `basePath`. `'options' => ['basePath' => Yii::getAlias('@alias/to/my/path')],`

Comment: @NikolajSarry не выходит...

Comment: и в превью пишет Not Found (#404): Page not found.

Comment: ну судя по ошибке у вас фреймворк ищет класс `Controller` в папке `/home/d/davgabih/team.umonreal.ru/public_html/controllers/` где его нет. вам нужно подключить класс `Controller` который вы расширяете через `use`

Comment: вообще при создании своего контролера надо прописывать `namespace app\controllers;`, а не `namespace controllers;` и `use yii\web\Controller;` который вы расширяете.